# Apple Store & Google Play Store Privacy Policy URL

Tags: android, ios, google-play, itunes-store

Can I use Google Drive Link as Privacy Policy in Apple and Google Play while publishing the Apps?

If not, is any way to host the privacy policy page on web and use it as free?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming.

Comment: Sorry, but it's a next step after programming. Developer does not only required programming help but the platforms or area where they work for or used them.

Comment: On Wordpress you can find a free plan: https://wordpress.com/pricing/

Comment: The question is badly written but relevant to programming because there is no separate "publish your program" forum on Stackoverflow, as far as I find. I came here with a related question and the preferred answer below is indeed helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, you can.**

The only requirement is that it should be available. The way you host it does not matter.

Comment: Great, will wait for more opinion. Will mark your answer as preferred then.